# How to replace back bar button with cancel bar button when pressing edit bar button?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is the bar button behavior found in the system language settings:

[image]

1. When the Edit bar button is pressed, the Back bar button will be replaced by the Cancel bar button.
2. When the Done bar button is pressed, the Cancel bar button will be replaced by the Back bar button.

I am using `UIViewController`.

I have no issue toggling between the Edit bar button and the Done bar button.

However, I am unsure how to toggle between the Back bar button and the Cancel bar button.

Could you guide me on how to achieve this?

This is my code snippet.

```
class NewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var editBarButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem!
    
    private var editMode: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func editButtonClick(_ sender: Any) {
        if editMode {
            editBarButtonItem.title = "Edit"
            
            // TOD: How to provide a back bar button item at top left?
        } else {
            editBarButtonItem.title = "Done"
            
            // TOD: How to provide a "Cancel" bar button item at top left?
        }
        
        editMode.toggle()
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, do not create your own Edit/Done button. `UIViewController` has built-in support for this.

```swift
func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}
```

[`editButtonItem`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621471-editbuttonitem) is provided for you. It toggles between "Edit" and "Done". When tapped, it calls the `UIViewController` method [`setEditing:animated:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621378-setediting) and it toggles the [`isEditing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621498-isediting) property. All you need to do is override that method to add/remove the "Cancel" button.

```swift
override func setEditing(_ editing: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setEditing(editing, animated: animated)

    if (editing) {
        // Edit has been pressed. Add the Cancel button
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancelHandler)), animated: animated)
    } else {
        // Done has been pressed. Remove the Cancel button and the back button will reappear
        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButton(nil, animated: animated)
    }
}

@objc func cancelHandler(_ button: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // handle the Cancel button
}
```

Using the built-in features to support a standard Edit/Done button is even more useful in a `UITableViewController` since the table view controller automatically sets the [`isEditing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1615001-isediting) property of its table view. The settings screen in your question is making use of `UITableViewController`.